# Does 3-SAT reduce to 3-CNF-SAT

Tags: computer-science, theory, computation-theory

I know that SAT goes to 3-SAT and SAT is reducible to CNF-SAT and CNF-SAT is reducible to 3-CNF-SAT but is 3-SAT reducible to 3-CNF-SAT?

Comment: Isn't the usual definition of 3SAT already 3-CNF-SAT?

Comment: Hmm, my 4 (=quad) SATellite dish uses BNC ... Perhaps you should ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @user2357112 I didnt think so I thought that the difference would be that it is now conjunctive normal form which is unique in itself.  ok I will but this is a theory of computation question

Comment: Isn't 3-SAT trivially reducible to SAT, whatever (sane) definition you use for 3-SAT? And then to CNF-SAT and 3-CNF_SAT?

Comment: Although I would also say that 3-SAT and 3-CNF-SAT are the same.